# Spring acegi security allows different user on the same browser tabs

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have configured in spring acegi security with my application. The spring acegi security allows the two different user to logged in at the same browser when i open the login page in two tab at same time and try to authenticate by different user one by one.

Does any one explain that how to solve the problem?

Comment: I just want to restict the user authentication if any user is already authenticated in same browser. 

Consider that I opened my login page in two tab. if i click login button with different user, the  two users can able to login.

Comment: The two users have different credentials like admin,userone

Comment: Two tabs will share the same session with the web container (as explained in [this FAQ](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/faq.html#faq-concurrent-session-same-browser)). So basically you can't really do this without rewriting your own parallel session management system. You need to use a different browser if you want to log in as a different user.